# Declare a variable inside a string in Angular

Tags: html, angular, internationalization

I am using Angular and under the i18n folder I have multiple json files like this one for different languages. I am looking for a dynamic way to use the "target" variable inside the string.

```
  {
      "title": "Connection,
      "targets": {
        "facebook": "Facebook",
        "instagram": "Instagram",
        "linkedin": "LinkedIn",
      },
      "message-success": "You connected successfully!",
      "message-failure": "You're connection failed",
      "failure-title": "Why did the connection to (here I want to use one of the targets, something like {{target}}) failed?"
    }
```

and then display it in the html.

```
 <div [hidden]="!error">
    <[ngClass]="'-background-grey-4 spacing padded'">{{'failure-title'}}</p-text>      
  </div>
```

Comment: You are talking about rendering a string template at runtime, you should use a library for that, e.g. [liquidjs](https://liquidjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood right, you could try to put the JSON string into an object and then access the object properties in the component.
You could then access to the properties doing objName.targets

To translate the JSON into ad object use JSON.parse(yourText).

Before doing this create a model (a class to define the object) in the same or the shared folder (for example target.model.ts).

To define the object:

```
export class connectionStatus { constructor(public title: string, etc...) }
```

Define all the properties of the object. They have to match the ones you read from file.

To parse the JSON:

```
let connectionStatusLocale: {
    title: string,
    targets: {facebook: 'Facebook', etc...},
    etc...
  } = JSON.parse(string);   //where string is the text you have read from a file

  this.conectionStatus = connectionStatusLocale;
```

When converting a string define the type before parsing to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you can utilize the `translate` pipe to use the property and dynamically pass a value for substituting `{{target}}`.

```html
<div [hidden]="!error">
  <p-text [ngClass]="'-background-grey-4 spacing padded'">
    {{ "failure-title" | translate : { target: yourValue } }}
  </p-text>      
</div>
```